# Continuum hypothesis analogue for substructures

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, descriptive-set-theory

*Throughout, "theory" means "possibly-incomplete first-order theory in a countable language."*

---

Say that a theory $T$ **has CHS** (= **c**ontinuum **h**ypothesis for **s**ubstructures) iff for every countable $\mathcal{M}\models T$, the set of isomorphism types of substructures of $\mathcal{M}$ also satisfying $T$ is either countable or size continuum. For example, the theory of linear orders has CHS: since $\mathbb{Q}$ has continuum-many nonisomorphic suborders only scattered linear orders could possibly be counterexamples, and they're handled by Laver's inductive analysis of scattered linear orders (see the introduction of [Equimorphism Invariants for Scattered Linear Orderings by Montalban](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eantonio/papers/scattered.pdf)).

My question is whether this is in fact trivial:

> Does *every* theory have CHS?

I don't see how to produce a counterexample, but I also don't see how to even start a proof of a positive result here. EDIT: I would be happy with an answer conditional on Vaught's conjecture.

Two quick comments:

- There is no obvious descriptive-set-theoretic obstacle: given a countable structure $\mathfrak{A}$ we can think of substructures of $\mathfrak{A}$ as points in Cantor space, and isomorphism then corresponds to a $\Sigma^1_1$ equivalence relation on Cantor space, but $\Sigma^1_1$ equivalence relations on Cantor space *can* have $\aleph_1$-many classes even if $2^{\aleph_0}\not=\aleph_1$.
- If $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, then the question as written has a trivial affirmative answer. Analogously to [the situation for Vaught's conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/175987/how-do-we-know-if-vaughts-conjecture-is-absolute), there is an "absolute" version of the question: namely, ask whether every theory $T$ has the property that for every $\mathfrak{A}\models T$ with underlying set $\mathbb{N}$, there is a perfect set $P\subseteq 2^\omega$ such that the substructures of $\mathfrak{A}$ corresponding to the elements of $P$ are non-isomorphic. This is not trivialized by cardinal arithmetic, and in the end is probably the "right" version of the question to ask.

Comment: I have a feeling that the answer is probably trivial (in hindsight) or resolves the Vaught's conjecture.

Comment: @tomasz I've edited to address that. Note that as far as I can tell the question remains nontrivial even if VC is assumed.

Comment: Does the problem become trivial if we count substructures satisfying T instead of isomorphism types of substructures satisfying T?

Comment: @JohnToh Yes: the set of substructures of $\mathcal{M}$ is a closed set in an appropriate Polish space, and so is either countable or of size continuum.